# spfx Global Term Store without using get

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, term-store

Just wondering whats the best way to get the name of the Global Term store without hard coding it?

I have this at the moment

```
var termStoreName = "Taxonomy_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const store: ITermStore = await taxonomy.termStores.getByName(termStoreName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it as below in SP Online:

1) Add the below import statement:

```
import { taxonomy, ITermStoreData} from "@pnp/sp-taxonomy";
```

2) After that you can get the name of the termstore as below:

```
taxonomy.termStores.get().then((d: ITermStoreData[]) => {      
  if(d.length > 0){
    var termStoreName = d[0].Name;
    console.log(termStoreName);
  }      
});
```